# Ruby read file_name with gets

Tags: ruby, file, file-handling

I have a beginners coding task, first step is my program "should prompt the user to enter a filename of a file that contains the following information:" There's already pre-made code to work on, a "music_player.rb" (where I have to write the code) and "albums.text" (which is the file I want to read from)

I know `a_file = File.new("mydata.txt", "r")` is to read from file. I'm trying to do:

```
file_name = gets()
a_file = File.new("#{file_name}" , "r") # (line 13)
```

I keep getting error

```
music_player_with_menu.rb:13:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - albums.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
```

when I enter `albums.txt`. If I just remove `gets` and have `File.new("albums.txt" , "r")` it works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can see what Todd A. Jacobs is describing if you insert the line `p filename` between the `gets` and the attempt to open the file.  Also, `gets` returns a string so you don't need the "#{...}" construct, just use `File.new(file_name, "r")` after `chomp`ing.

Comment: Yep his answer helped me out, I just had to use .chomp. I'm not sure if I need to edit this post or something to show my problem has been answered , I haven't used stackoverflow much before.

Comment: You can upvote all answers you feel contributed to your underrstanding, but if you consider a particular answer to be the one that helped you solve the problem you click on the checkmark to the left of it.  That marks it as "the answer".  You should also probably take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and at least glance at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you're going to stick around.  Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to read from `mydata.txt\n` is going to raise an exception unless the filename actually ends in `\n`, which is rarely the case. This is because you're using #gets, which includes the newline character(s) from the user pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

When you read from STDIN, you will get a line-ending (e.g. `\n` on *nix, and `\r\n` on Windows). So, when you call #gets, you almost always need to call [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) on the result.

```
file_name = gets
#=> "foo\n"

file_name = gets.chomp
#=> "foo"
```

Comment: @EugeneStanko The point is that trying to read `foo` when the filename is actually `foo\n` (regardless of how your OS represents it visually) will correctly raise Errno::ENOENT because you're trying to read a file that doesn't exist in the directory. Q.E.D.